# Is this version of SAT NP-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Given a SAT instance such that:

1. Each clause is of length at most 4.
2. Negative literal occurs only in clauses of length=2.
3. Each length 2 clause has at most 1 negative literal.

Is this version of SAT NP-Complete?

Comment: This implies that the CNF is a dual Horn formula (every clause contains at most one negative literal), hence it is solvable in polynomial time.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank a lot. And the modification where: (1) Each clause of length at most 4 (2) Each length=4 clause has all literals negative (3) Each length=3 has no negative literal (4) Each length=2 clause has exactly 1 (or at most one) negative literal. This doesn't seem to be Horn SAT so am I correct that this is NPComplete?

Comment: Yes, this is NP-complete. With a pair of a purely positive and purely negative clause $x\lor y$ and $\neg x\lor\neg y$, you can define $y$ to be equivalent to $\neg x$. Using these extension variables, you can express any 3-CNF as a set of purely positive 3-clauses. Now, you do not allow purely positive or purely negative clauses of length 2, but only of length 3 or 4 (respectively), but this is of no consequence, as you can introduce a new variable equivalent to an old one by a pair of 2-clauses with one negative literal each.

Comment: It appears the question is solved now. The site works best when answers are written in the answers section, so I encourage anyone to write up an answer to be upvoted.